How do I remove the delay when using a key remapped to `k`?
I use the Dvorak layout and am trying to start using Neovim. By default, the arrow buttons were scattered all across the keyboard, so I created this script to remap them:
local function noremap(shortcut, command)
  -- vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("", shortcut, command, { noremap = true, silent = true })
  vim.keymap.set("", shortcut, command, { silent = true, noremap = true })
end

-- h is already in the right place
noremap("c", "k")
noremap("t", "j")
noremap("n", "l")

-- the keys I remapped to might be used for other commands, so I basically swap them
noremap("k", "c")
noremap("j", "t")
noremap("l", "n")

-- same for uppercase
noremap("K", "C")
noremap("J", "T")
noremap("L", "N")


Note that I'm using i, not h, for up. This is because I have set set up a layer on my keyboard with IJKL as arrows a long time ago and am already used to this, plus this makes more sense.
In raw Neovim, this worked fine, but then I installed LazyVim. I managed to get the remaps working by moving the code to lua/config/keymaps.lua, but there's a problem: when I press C (aka I on qwerty) for UP, there's a 0.5 second delay before the cursor moves up. RIGHT, LEFT and DOWN work fine.
I experimented with remapping UP to other buttons and the lag persisted. It disappears only if I don't remap it at all.
How could I fix this?

In standard Neovim  the c key command is the command for change c. It wait for a move (or a text objet) to determine what to change, switching to operation pending mode.
LazyVim comes with which-key.nvim that provides hints when in operation pending mode (e.g.: c or d) to complete the operation.
To solve the problem you probably have to either:

Disable which-key.nvim
Restrict it to not make suggestions for operation pending mode (I'm not sure it is possible)

One way to disable which-key.nvim in LazyVim is to add a ~/.config/nvim/lua/plugins/disabled.lua file with the following content:
return {
    { "folke/which-key.nvim", enabled = false },
}


There is Dvorak support in an optional plugin distributed with Vim (:edit $VIMRUNTIME/macros/README.txt):
The following have been moved to an optional package.  Add the command to your
vimrc file to use the package:

packadd! dvorak     " Dvorak keyboard support; adds mappings

In particular, $VIMRUNTIME/pack/dist/opt/dvorak/dvorak/enable.vim might interest you.
Also see :help mbyte-keymap for another way to approach this; Vim comes with $VIMRUNTIME/keymap/dvorak.vim, too, so :set keymap=dvorak ought to work.
